# SHA1 and SHA256 initial digest to start from

Tags: hash

Let's say I have:
C = A + B
where A and B contain strings and the plus sign means concatenation.
I already hashed A with SHA1 and SHA256 and got a digests.
I forget what the original A string was, but I want to get the digests like I wanted to hash the entire C string. Can I initialize these hash functions to A's digest and continue hashing the B string and get the same digests as if I had been hashing C from the start?

Comment: I believe (*believe*) this would be a [length extension attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack), which is indeed possible with SHA1 and SHA256.

Comment: I have found hlextend Python module that seems to help in generating the new digest. In the example on their github, which string is my A string? 'file' or 'hello'? Would it work if I leave the other one a blank string?

Comment: @WanderNauta, it is indeed a length extension attack and it is possible (although I don't know enough details to answer). Also see ["Merkle-Damgard construction" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction)